# How can I arrange a bar plot using ggplot2 based on the distribution proportions of variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way to arrange the bar plot produced with ggplot2 by descending order of "utsugds2gp_22(happy condition)"  that equal to 1 (category=not happy) within each scode1_22 group (area).
The original bar plot I generated is below:

[image]

My codes are as following :

```
# Create the scode1_22 vector
scode1_22 <- c(
  "12217001", "12217001", "12217001", "12217001", "12217001", 
  "12217002", "12217002", "12217002", "12217002", "12217002", 
  "12217002", "12217002", "12217002", "12217002", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", 
  "12217004", "12217004", "NA", "12217004", "12217004", 
  "12217004", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217004", "12217004", 
  "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", 
  "12217004", "NA", "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", 
  "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", "12217005", "12217005", 
  "12217005", "12217005", "12217005", "12217005", "12217005", 
  "12217005", "12217005"
)

# Create the utsugds2gp_22 vector
utsugds2gp_22 <- c(
  0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
  1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
  1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,1
)

# Create the income_3gp vector
income_3gp <- c(
  1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
  2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
  1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
  3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
  3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
  3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
  3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
  1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1
)

dataset <- data.frame(scode1_22, utsugds2gp_22)
print(dataset)

fill <- c("white", "#E1B378")

dataset %>% 
  filter(!is.na(scode1_22), !is.na(utsugds2gp_22)) %>% 
  mutate(
    scode1_22 = factor(scode1_22, levels = c("12217001", "12217002", "12217003", "12217004", "12217005"), labels = c("area1", "area2", "area3", "area4", "area5")),
    utsugds2gp_22 = factor(utsugds2gp_22, levels = c(0:1), labels = c(" happy", "not happy"))
  ) %>%
  group_by(scode1_22) %>%
  mutate(scode1_22 = factor(scode1_22, levels = unique(scode1_22))) %>%
  arrange(scode1_22, desc(utsugds2gp_22 == "not happy")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = scode1_22, fill = utsugds2gp_22)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", col = "black") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "happy condition(%)", values = fill) + 
  labs(x = "area", y = "happy condition(%)")
```

Ideally, I would like my result to resemble the one shown in this image as a reference:[How to re-order bar plot with ggplot2 by distribution proportions of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73907442/how-to-re-order-bar-plot-with-ggplot2-by-distribution-proportions-of-variables?newreg=ab518152fa2043db96f43998e4677d0c)

[image]

I have explored various methods, but unfortunately, none of them have been successful. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

2023/06/08 New question
I have a query regarding the previous result. My next step involves using the 'facet_wrap' function to create separate panels (STEP4) of bars and add the average value(STEP5) .

My codes are as following :

```
# Create the scode1_22 vector
scode1_22 <- c(
  "12217001", "12217001", "12217001", "12217001", "12217001", 
  "12217002", "12217002", "12217002", "12217002", "12217002", 
  "12217002", "12217002", "12217002", "12217002", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", 
  "12217004", "12217004", "NA", "12217004", "12217004", 
  "12217004", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", 
  "12217003", "12217003", "12217003", "12217004", "12217004", 
  "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", 
  "12217004", "NA", "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", 
  "12217004", "12217004", "12217004", "12217005", "12217005", 
  "12217005", "12217005", "12217005", "12217005", "12217005", 
  "12217005", "12217005"
)

# Create the utsugds2gp_22 vector
utsugds2gp_22 <- c(
  0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
  1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
  1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,1
)

# Create the income_3gp vector
income_3gp <- c(
  1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
  2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
  1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
  3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
  3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
  3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
  3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
  1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1
)


dataset <- data.frame(scode1_22, utsugds2gp_22)

fill <- c("white", "#E1B378")

library(dplyr)
dataset %>% 
  # STEP1: scode1_22 has values of "NA" text, different from NA missing value indivator
  filter(scode1_22 != "NA", !is.na(utsugds2gp_22)) %>% 
  mutate(
    scode1_22 = factor(scode1_22, levels = c("12217001", "12217002", "12217003", "12217004", "12217005"), labels = c("area1", "area2", "area3", "area4", "area5")),
    utsugds2gp_22 = factor(utsugds2gp_22, levels = c(0:1), labels = c(" happy", "not happy"))
  ) %>%
  
  # STEP2: order
  count(scode1_22, utsugds2gp_22) %>%
  mutate(share = n / sum(n), .by = scode1_22) %>%
  arrange(utsugds2gp_22, -share) %>%            # sorts lowest happy share first
  mutate(scode1_22 = forcats::fct_inorder(scode1_22)) %>% # factor in that order
  ggplot(aes(x = scode1_22, y = share, fill = utsugds2gp_22)) +
  geom_col(col = "black") +
  
  # STEP3: FROM ORIG
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "happy condition(%)", values = fill) + 
  labs(x = "area", y = "happy condition(%)")+

  # STEP4: grouped by income_3gp
  facet_wrap(~income_3gp, ncol=1, strip.position = "left") 
  
# STEP5: add the average value on each graph 
   geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(utsugds2gp_22)), color = "blue", size = 1, by=income_3gp)
```

My ideal outcome is

[image]

Comment: I'd add `mutate(scode1_22 = fct_inorder(scode1_22))` after your `arrange` line, so that the factor ordering will reflect that ordering.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried it but the ordering did not reflect accurately.

Comment: Happy to help further if you can provide some sample data in your question that would let me test a solution on my computer instead of in my imagination.

Comment: Thank you! It's really kind of you.Do you mind I provide dta file to you? where you can download the file(kaV1.dta) from the file tensfer website:  https://filetransfer.io/data-package/Vu7ODIkb#link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the information. I've edited my codes as you can see from the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% 
  # scode1_22 has values of "NA" text, different from NA missing value indivator
  filter(scode1_22 != "NA", !is.na(utsugds2gp_22)) %>% 
  mutate(
    scode1_22 = factor(scode1_22, levels = c("12217001", "12217002", "12217003", "12217004", "12217005"), labels = c("area1", "area2", "area3", "area4", "area5")),
    utsugds2gp_22 = factor(utsugds2gp_22, levels = c(0:1), labels = c(" happy", "not happy"))
  ) %>%

  # NEW PART
  count(scode1_22, utsugds2gp_22) %>%
  mutate(share = n / sum(n), .by = scode1_22) %>%
  arrange(utsugds2gp_22, -share) %>%            # sorts lowest happy share first
  mutate(scode1_22 = forcats::fct_inorder(scode1_22)) %>% # factor in that order
  ggplot(aes(x = scode1_22, y = share, fill = utsugds2gp_22)) +
  geom_col(col = "black") +

  # FROM ORIG
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "happy condition(%)", values = fill) + 
  labs(x = "area", y = "happy condition(%)")
```

[image]

Comment: You are truly amazing! Thank you for providing such detailed information. I followed your guidance, revised my original code, and it works perfectly now! Thank you!

Comment: Hello John, I'm not sure if it's appropriate to ask another question here, so please let me know if I should refrain. I have a query regarding the previous result. My next step involves using the 'facet_wrap' function to create separate panels of bars. However, when I attempted to execute the code 'facet_wrap(~income_3gp, ncol=1, strip.position = "left"), it didn't produce the desired outcome. Could you kindly assist me with this issue?

Comment: What outcome did it produce and what outcome did you want?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the information of coding and my ideal outcome.  My coding did not go well, the error  shows "At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `income_3gp`".....